# Update Statement into Textboxes c# data type mismatched in criteria

Tags: c#

Attempting to use the update Statement but when I execute the program it claims:
user type mismatch in data criteria

When I click the updatebutton, I want for the database to update where ID =

```
private void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //OPENING CONNECTION

    db.Open();
    int idd = int.Parse( InstructorIDText.Text);

    OleDbCommand df = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Instructors SET FirstName='"+FNText.Text+"',LastName='"+Lntext.Text+"',Street='"+StreetText.Text+"',City='"+CityText.Text+"',State='"+StateText.Text+"',Zip='"+ZipText.Text+"',Office='"+OfficeText.Text+"',EMail='"+EmailText.Text+"' WHERE ID = " + idd +"", db);
    //creating parameters
    df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", InstructorIDText.Text);

    df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FNText.Text);
    df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", Lntext.Text);
    df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Street", StreetText.Text);
    df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", CityText.Text);
    df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", StateText.Text);
    df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", ZipText.Text);
    df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Office", OfficeText.Text);
    df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMail", EmailText.Text);
    df.ExecuteNonQuery();
    db.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@parameter` in query instead of concatenating exact values

For MS-SQL

```
//OPENING CONNECTION

db.Open();
int idd = int.Parse(InstructorIDText.Text);

OleDbCommand df = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Instructors SET FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName,Street=@Street,City=@City,State=@State,Zip=@Zip,Office=@Office,EMail=@EMail WHERE ID = @ID", db);
//creating parameters
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", InstructorIDText.Text);

df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FNText.Text);
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", Lntext.Text);
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Street", StreetText.Text);
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", CityText.Text);
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", StateText.Text);
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", ZipText.Text);
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Office", OfficeText.Text);
df.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMail", EmailText.Text);
df.ExecuteNonQuery();
db.Close();
```

Comment: I upvoted, its a better answer because it shows how the modifications should be made.

Answer (score -1):

When using add with value use the variable idd instead of the .Text property. The query is expecting an int for your @id parameter but you are supplying a string.

See if that helps